# Plagiarism with Jplag for different languages

Tags: plagiarism-detection

I have a bunch of codes from students for a coding question. I am using Jplag to find the similarities between their codes.

```
java -jar jplag-yourVersion.jar -l java17 -r /tmp/jplag_results_exerise1/ -s /path/to/exercise1
```

This kind of syntax works for single language. But i am having codes in multiple languages like c, c++, java, python, ruby.

Can some one suggest me a method to process all the codes which are in different languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to these references, it is not possible to detect cross-language plagiarism with JPLAG.

[Detecting source code reuse across programming languages](https://users.dsic.upv.es/~prosso/resources/FloresEtAl_SEPLN11.pdf):

> "JPlag is able to detect source code reuse in different programming languages although at monolingual level, that is, one programming language at a time."

[(CLSCR) CROSS LANGUAGE SOURCE CODE REUSE DETECTION USING INTERMEDIATE LANGUAGE](http://www.uni-weimar.de/medien/webis/events/pan-at-fire-15/pan15-papers-final/pan15-source-code-reuse-detection/shah15-notebook.pdf):

> "Some of the tools are Sherlock, MOSS, JPLAG etc. All of these tools detect mono language plagiarism"